# What format is used in order to add data in swagger in a related table?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger

When i do a post or a put (data are comming [fromform]) the interface of swagger show me the form in order to enter data. There is a related classe and the interface give me the possibility to add items. I tried various format but nothing seems to work. Might you tell me what is the right format accepted ?

[image]

The model is

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Achat> Achats { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VideoLangue> VideoLangue { get; set; }
}

public class Langue
    {
        public int LangueId { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<VideoLangue> VideoLangue { get; set; }
    }

public class Achat
    {
        public int AchatId { get; set; }
        public float Prix { get; set; }
        public virtual int UtilisateurId { get; set; }
        public virtual int VideoId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The API spec seems to be missing the info about the expected array structure. Do you have access to the source code? If yes, please post the class/interface code with annotations and let us know which library you use (e.g. Swashbuckle, Swagger-Net, or something else). Or if this this a third-party API, contact the API vendor.

Comment: Hello helene, i created a project via visual studio, made a model with related classes. When I add an element in one of the related classes via the sawgger I have this interface to add items but some json doesn't seem to work. do you have any idea ?I did not modify the default code of the swagger.

Comment: Please post the controller code and the code of the "Name of classe" model with annotations.

Comment: Hello Helen, i add the model in the question. Thank you